# couchbase server ops per second

Tags: json, couchbase, bucket

I have a question, just want to save a json value in a bucket. first, i set the value size is 2 byte, and set the value to the bucket, the web console show me the sets per sec is 15K, and i set the value size is 10KB, and set the value, the sets per sec become 500,when the json value size  become more big, and i use get and set operator on the bucket also become very slower, how can i do; i think i can decrease value size, but it is difficulty, have some other ways to improve the get and set operator'is speed

Comment: We use Couchbase for large online gaming system with millions of keys and very large structures and it is incredibly fast. If you are experiencing problems it probably has more to do with you cluster and hardware. How big is your cluster? What sort of hardware is it running on?

Comment: what is the large structures that you say, can you provide a example about it, my cluster size is 30G, my server RAM is 32G

Comment: In general we try to keep structures under 16K, and that is where you are saying you are starting to experience slow speeds. How many machines do you have in your cluster and what programming language are you using?

Comment: two machines in my cluster during the test, when the product on line it will increase ten machines, but i found the max number of replica is 3 on web console; is it really that  the max number of replica is 3?rei use python develop the product

Answer (score 0):

We overcame speed problems by using a custom transcoder to zip the data. Especially for larger keys 16K+ this improved the speed a lot. Since you use the python SDK you will be interested in this:
http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-python-client-1.2.0/html/api/transcoder.html

The other solution for speed problems is to do batch operations wherever possible:
http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-python-client-1.2.0/html/api/couchbase.html#batch-operation-pipeline

Since your hardware seems adequate, Couchbase recommend 4 CPU cores, you should also consider looking at your network interface. You will want to run at least 1Gbps lan between the machines in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

What mode of operation are you using your Client SDK? For maximum performance you want to ensure you are use asynchronous `get` and `set` operations, so you application isn't waiting for the operation to complete before scheduling the next operation.

In Python the default `set` method is synchronous, meaning the SDK will block and wait until the actual set operation has completed on the server. The Python client SDK support both the [Twisted](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-python-1.2/#twisted-interface) or [Gevent](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-python-1.2/#gevent-interface) event frameworks.

A good, simple test to check if you've maxed the Couchbase server or the bottleneck is simply in the client (which I suspect in this case) is to fire up a second instance of your application on a second app server. If your performance increases then you know the application is the bottleneck.

Comment: i was use the default method(just synchronous) in python ago,and yesterday i use twisted, and i found a question, when i  get or set method; just some operator has return result and many method was no return;and i set a variable that limit when the no return result method's number is 10000, and time.sleep(1); then i found when the no return result method's number is reach to 10000,the application will always sleep;and couchbase web console show me no get or set operator; it is why ?

Comment: @user3168625 - I suggest you ask that as a new question - comments aren't a good place to answer.